# use microsoft word's mergemail to create an orgchart

Tags: excel, ms-word, automation, mailmerge

I've been asked to create some sort of orgchart in Word.  I have an Excel sheet with two columns, `Employee_name` and `Dept_name` that come from some HR database.

I've been hoping of doing this the simple way by (ab)using Word's Mergemail feature.

Before spending a lot of time on this (not having used this feature before), I was wondering whether this is actually possible: My main challenge is to group the names by department.  There is a feature called "Directory" [1] that seems to be able to create lists of people, although it's listing people in alphabetical order, where I'd rather need to fill existing boxes (or circles in our case) with all the names that belong to that department.

Thanks for any help and pointers you can give.

[1] https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-directory-of-names-addresses-and-other-information-49afe95c-dc99-4cd3-85c7-3a80869cff90

PS: Not really a programming question, but I've seen Office-related questions on SO before.  My apologies!

Comment: pnuts - thanks, I might consider it, but will it help me to group names by department?

Comment: Ah sorry. I try again: Given a list of employees (name and the department they work for), group them in boxes, one per department. - Maybe I should look at VBA because looping over all departments and finding the corresponding employees would be easy in a programming environment.